# How can I allow users to select HTML elements of a remote site?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an idea for a project that has a bit of functionality I'm not sure how to implement: first, a user would be able to load up a web page and select elements on it. Those elements would then be recorded using JavaScript so that I can act on the selections the user made.

There's a plugin for Google Chrome called [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/chrome/) that does something similar: using the extension, the user can select elements on a page for the purposes of triggering the extension's functionality.

How can I accomplish something like this? Is there a JavaScript library (ideally open source) that can provide this type of functionality?

Comment: Provide what type of functionality, getting the selection range? That's [fairly trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1317740/886931).

Comment: @ggg : No, not selection range.  I want to know that they clicked "textbox1" and typed "blah blah" then clicked "checkbox1" and then clicked "button1" then keep track of that information as the page redirects somewhere else because of the button click, etc.

Comment: Well now I'm really confused. If you need to know what they did on a form, why not just submit the form and redirect them somewhere?

Comment: @ggg : The question specifically states "of a remote site".  Meaning, they provide a url and I monitor what they do there.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you want the library to do. Monitor what they do with a form and somehow defeat the cross-domain policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your questioin you are basically searching for a JS macro recorder? Maybe [this](http://blog.metawrap.com/2007/06/22/javascript-macro-recorder/) blogpost can be a starting point for your own developement.

[Update]
There are several ways you can achieve the functionality:

- Add JS to the site
- Write Browser extensions
- Use a [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)
- Use something like [Anonymouse.org](http://anonymouse.org) where the user enters a url and you rewrite the links to point to your site (or iframe)

Comment: "Macro recorder", thank you.  That's a phrase that will lead me the right direction.  This is a good first step.  If no one can provide a better alternative I'll probably accept your answer, however I'd like to do it without manually including .js files in a page.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright i don't know what your plans exactly are but basically including it into a page is the only way you can achieve this. The only other possibility is a bookmarklet or a browser specific solution.

Comment: The reason I don't want to have to include a file is that I want to make a commercial solution for non-tech people.  I would like to avoid the iMacro route of creating a different Extension for each major Browser and have all functionality be done through a web page.

Comment: The only way to do it without any type of extension or bookmarklet (which can easily be highly cross browser) or cooperation from the both websites, is to create a web proxy as mentioned by PizzaPill ( Anonymouse.org ) but this is fraught with complexity. These are your only options, at all, to "spy" on a web site using a different website.

Answer (score 2):

TIP: If you want to see how a browser extension for Chrome or Firefox does something: Download the file to your hard drive, rename the file extension to .zip, open it up and look at the code. Nearly all are written in Javascript.