# how to highlight all the occurrence of a particular string in a div with java script?

Tags: javascript, html

i need to highlight all the occurrences of a string in particular div by selecting a string, 
once i select a word and click a button it need to highlight all its occurrence inside a div,

eg - if i select

> cricket is game

it should highlight all the occurrences of cricket is game some may be like this  **cricket** is game or *cricket* **is game**

[image]

Comment: How does the user select a string?

Comment: Try this link: http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/

Comment: using mouse drag event (selecting a word or more)

Comment: That is easy, you would have found a lot of snippets for the taks. However, if your question is "*How to find and hightlight text across element boundaries?*" (non-trivial), ask that specificly.

Comment: ya exactly i want to highlight the word even with nested tags (across element boundaries)

Comment: have you tried the solution ?

Comment: @ Pranay Rana - i tried it, but it fails when it cross element boundaries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the browser to do the hard work for you using a `TextRange` in IE and `window.find()` in other browsers.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887719/96100) shows how to do it. It will match text that crosses element boundaries and does the highlighting for you using `document.execCommand()`.

Alternatively, James Padolsey recently published a script that I haven't used but looks like it could help: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved/

Answer (score 4):

[mark.js](https://markjs.io/) seems pretty good for this. Here's my 3 line fiddle to take an html 'string' and highlight the search string.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html_string = "<b>Major Tom to groundcontrol.</b> Earth is blue <span> and there's something </span> i can do";

    var with_highlight = $("<div/>").html(html_string).mark("can");

    $("#msg").html(with_highlight);
})
```

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeep_muthangi/4axfxv9z)

Comment: Goot catch! Just an information about the fiddle: jQuery is inserted two times and mark.min.js isn't necessary for jquery.mark.min.js

Answer (score 3):

You can tryout this script  

## Demo

 
in `highlightSearchTerms` function of this script `var bodyText = document.body.innerHTML;` get replace by your divid and than it will do the task for you..

```
/*
 * This is the function that actually highlights a text string by
 * adding HTML tags before and after all occurrences of the search
 * term. You can pass your own tags if you'd like, or if the
 * highlightStartTag or highlightEndTag parameters are omitted or
 * are empty strings then the default <font> tags will be used.
 */
function doHighlight(bodyText, searchTerm, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag) 
{
  // the highlightStartTag and highlightEndTag parameters are optional
  if ((!highlightStartTag) || (!highlightEndTag)) {
    highlightStartTag = "<font style='color:blue; background-color:yellow;'>";
    highlightEndTag = "</font>";
  }

  // find all occurences of the search term in the given text,
  // and add some "highlight" tags to them (we're not using a
  // regular expression search, because we want to filter out
  // matches that occur within HTML tags and script blocks, so
  // we have to do a little extra validation)
  var newText = "";
  var i = -1;
  var lcSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  var lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();

  while (bodyText.length > 0) {
    i = lcBodyText.indexOf(lcSearchTerm, i+1);
    if (i < 0) {
      newText += bodyText;
      bodyText = "";
    } else {
      // skip anything inside an HTML tag
      if (bodyText.lastIndexOf(">", i) >= bodyText.lastIndexOf("<", i)) {
        // skip anything inside a <script> block
        if (lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("/script>", i) >= lcBodyText.lastIndexOf("<script", i)) {
          newText += bodyText.substring(0, i) + highlightStartTag + bodyText.substr(i, searchTerm.length) + highlightEndTag;
          bodyText = bodyText.substr(i + searchTerm.length);
          lcBodyText = bodyText.toLowerCase();
          i = -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return newText;
}
/*
 * This is sort of a wrapper function to the doHighlight function.
 * It takes the searchText that you pass, optionally splits it into
 * separate words, and transforms the text on the current web page.
 * Only the "searchText" parameter is required; all other parameters
 * are optional and can be omitted.
 */
function highlightSearchTerms(searchText, treatAsPhrase, warnOnFailure, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag)
{
  // if the treatAsPhrase parameter is true, then we should search for 
  // the entire phrase that was entered; otherwise, we will split the
  // search string so that each word is searched for and highlighted
  // individually
  if (treatAsPhrase) {
    searchArray = [searchText];
  } else {
    searchArray = searchText.split(" ");
  }

  if (!document.body || typeof(document.body.innerHTML) == "undefined") {
    if (warnOnFailure) {
      alert("Sorry, for some reason the text of this page is unavailable. Searching will not work.");
    }
    return false;
  }

  var bodyText = document.body.innerHTML;
  for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
    bodyText = doHighlight(bodyText, searchArray[i], highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag);
  }

  document.body.innerHTML = bodyText;
  return true;
}

/*
 * This displays a dialog box that allows a user to enter their own
 * search terms to highlight on the page, and then passes the search
 * text or phrase to the highlightSearchTerms function. All parameters
 * are optional.
 */
function searchPrompt(defaultText, treatAsPhrase, textColor, bgColor)
{
  // This function prompts the user for any words that should
  // be highlighted on this web page
  if (!defaultText) {
    defaultText = "";
  }

  // we can optionally use our own highlight tag values
  if ((!textColor) || (!bgColor)) {
    highlightStartTag = "";
    highlightEndTag = "";
  } else {
    highlightStartTag = "<font style='color:" + textColor + "; background-color:" + bgColor + ";'>";
    highlightEndTag = "</font>";
  }

  if (treatAsPhrase) {
    promptText = "Please enter the phrase you'd like to search for:";
  } else {
    promptText = "Please enter the words you'd like to search for, separated by spaces:";
  }

  searchText = prompt(promptText, defaultText);

  if (!searchText)  {
    alert("No search terms were entered. Exiting function.");
    return false;
  }

  return highlightSearchTerms(searchText, treatAsPhrase, true, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/wDN5M/

```
function getSelText() {
  var txt = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
        txt = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML.split(txt).join('<span class="highlight">' + txt + '</span>');
}
```

See: [Get selected text on the page (not in a textarea) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317727/get-selected-text-on-the-page-not-in-a-textarea-with-jquery)

If you want it to work across element boundaries your code will need to be more involved than this. [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) will make your life easier when doing the necessary DOM traversal and manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to iterate over all Elements in your div (Don't know if you have other elements in the div) and then a Regular Expression and do a greedy match to find all occurrences of the selected string in your text(s) in the elements.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find needed substrings in needed text and wrap them with <span class="search-highlight">. Every time you need to highlight another strings, you just get all the .search-highlight spans and turn their outerHtml into innerHtml.
So the code will be close to:

```
function highLight(substring, block) {
   $(block).find(".search-highlight").each(function () {
      $(this).outerHtml($(this).html());
   });
   // now the block is free from previous highlights

   $(block).html($(block).html().replace(/substring/g, '<span class="search-highlight">' + substring + '</span>'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id=f1 name="f1" action="" 
onSubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null && this.t1.value!='')
findString(this.t1.value);return false"
>
<input type="text" id=t1 name=t1size=20>
<input type="submit" name=b1 value="Find">
</form>
<script>
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Much better to use rather JavaScript str.replace() function then window.find() to find all occurrences of a filter value. Iterating through the whole page might be bit complicated but if you want to search within a parent div, or within a table str.replace() is just simpler.

In your example you have only one DIV, that is even simpler. Here is what I would do (having your DIV an ID: myDIV):

```
        //Searching for "District Court"
        var filter = "District Court";  

        //Here we create the highlight with html tag: <mark> around filter
        var span = '<mark>' + filter + '</mark>';

        //take the content of the DIV you want to highlight
        var searchInthisDiv =   document.getElementById("MyDiv");
        var textInDiv       =   searchInthisDiv.innerHTML;

        //needed this var for replace function, do the replace (the highlighting)
        var highlighted     =   textInDiv.replace(filter,span); 
        textInDiv.innerHTML =   highlighted;
```

The trick is to replace the search string with a span that is having the filter within a  tag. 
str.replace replaces all occurrences of the search string, so no need to bother with looping. Loop can be used to loop through DIVs or other DOM elements.