# search and highlight text in webview in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have load the local html file in the web engine. i need to search and highlight the given string in the web view page.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to do it? I''m stuck at it as well...

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790375/how-to-highlight-all-the-occurrence-of-a-particular-string-in-a-div-with-java-sc) out :)

Comment: You need to write Javascript code, wich you can call over java with the Nashorn Api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx | Search and Highlight text | Add Search Bar for loaded web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418626/javafx-search-and-highlight-text-add-search-bar-for-loaded-web-page)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using reflection, it can be done natively in Java code.

WebEngine has a private field page of type [WebPage](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/webkit/WebPage.java), which in turn has this method which exactly does what you want:

```
// Find in page
public boolean find(String stringToFind, boolean forward, boolean wrap, boolean matchCase) {
    // ...
}
```

So to access this find() method you have to do:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

try {
    Field pageField = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("page");
    pageField.setAccessible(true);

    WebPage page = (com.sun.webkit.WebPage) pageField.get(engine);
    page.find("query", true, true, false);
} catch(Exception e) { /* log error could not access page */ }
```