# JavaFx | Search and Highlight text | Add Search Bar for loaded web page

Tags: html, search, user-interface, javafx

I used the SimpleSwingBrowser example (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm) and added some code of my own for log tailing.

I wanted to add a search bar ability to it (Search and Highlight text).

After googling for hours and self experiments, I didn't find a way to do it.
Can someone give me a kick-off direction for writing such ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Suggestions for a JavaScript based solution**

Use an existing JavaScript highlighting library such as [jQuery highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) or [hilitor.js](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight).

**Suggestions for a Java based solution**

Use the Java w3c DOM API to perform operations on the WebEngine document object after the document has been loaded.

**To get a Search API in the JavaFX WebView core implementation**

I created feature request [RT-23383 Text search support for WebView](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23383).  The feature request is currently open and unactioned - you can create an account in the issue tracker and vote for or comment on the feature request.

**Sample**

This sample uses jQuery highlight.  The user types the word to be highlighted into the text field, then presses the highlight button to highlight all occurrences of the word in the page or to remove highlight button to clear all marked highlights.  You could modify the sample to allow further jQuery based searches to scroll to a next and previously highlighted word.

I tried to get it to work with any arbitrary web page, but that logic defeated me.  If you control the source of the page you want to search and can add the reference to the jQuery highlight plugin and it's style class to your page, something like this sample program might be an option.

[image: highlight]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewSearch extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html");

        final TextField searchField = new TextField("light");
        searchField.setPromptText("Enter the text you would like to highlight and press ENTER to highlight");
        searchField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                if (engine.getDocument() != null) {
                    highlight(
                            engine,
                            searchField.getText()
                    );
                }
            }
        });

        final Button highlightButton = new Button("Highlight");
        highlightButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        highlightButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                searchField.fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
            }
        });
        final Button removeHighlightButton = new Button("Remove Highlight");
        removeHighlightButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                removeHighlight(
                        engine
                );

            }
        });
        removeHighlightButton.setCancelButton(true);

        HBox controls = new HBox(10);
        controls.getChildren().setAll(
                highlightButton,
                removeHighlightButton
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().setAll(searchField, controls, webView);
        searchField.setMinHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        controls.setMinHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        controls.disableProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().runningProperty());
        searchField.disableProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().runningProperty());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        primaryStage.show();

        webView.requestFocus();
    }

    private void highlight(WebEngine engine, String text) {
        engine.executeScript("$('body').removeHighlight().highlight('" + text + "')");
    }

    private void removeHighlight(WebEngine engine) {
        engine.executeScript("$('body').removeHighlight()");
    }

}
```

Comment: 10x for your answer. I use this code on a PC. I can't compile your code. Is it for Android?

Comment: No.  It is for JavaFX 2.x+, which currently doesn't run on Android.  I don't know why you cannot compile.

Comment: Ok. I manage to work it out. Thank you. It does work. But how can i run this on any web page, not just ones with jquery and the highlight js declared on the page?

Comment: @SharonBL as I said in my answer "I tried to get it to work with any arbitrary web page, but that logic defeated me".  I can get just jQuery to work on any web page using this [JQueryWebView support function](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942), but the combo of JQuery+Highlight plugin on any arbitrary web page where do you do not control the content surpassed my weak JavaScript skills.

Comment: 10x again. I was so pleased with your help, i missed that comment. I'll keep try to work it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: I managed to operate this. Now I'm facing a new problem... I want to be able to jump from all the highlighted occurrences. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: OK. Found a solution :-) Using this...
window.find('Text')