# highlighter class support in webview javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Can i use highlighter class to highlight the all occurrences of a word in web view as it is possible in jeditorpane in swing .

Actually i want to highlight  a given word in the webpage displayed in webview using 
       javafx but i am not able to do that is it possible as it is in swing jeditorpane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use a JavaScript solution for this as there is currently (JavaFX 2.2) no Java API to support this functionality.  See [how to highlight all the occurrence of a particular string in a div with java script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790375/how-to-highlight-all-the-occurrence-of-a-particular-string-in-a-div-with-java-sc)